# The linear sum of a finite number of finitely generated submodules is finitely generated.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Is the finite sum of finitely generated submodules finitely generated. Below, I formulate this question precisely and give my answer to it. It is an evident claim but it is nowhere to find in the literature, so I leave it here to discuss if someone disagrees with it.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ be an $A$-module and let $N_1, \dots, N_n$ be a finite family of finitely generated submodules of $M$. Then the linear sum of submodules $\sum_{i=1}^nN_i:=\mathrm{Span}_A(\bigcup_iN_i)$ is finitely generated over $A$, too.

**Proof**:

For every element $x\in\sum_{i=1}^nN_i$, by definition, we have
$x=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ with $x_i\in N_i$. Since for every $i=1, \dots, n$, the submodule $N_i$ is finitely generated with generators $e_1^{(i)}, \dots, e_{m_i}^{(i)}$, we have

$x_i=\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}a_j^{(i)}e_j^{(i)}$ and hence

$$x=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}a_j^{(i)}e_j^{(i)}.$$

Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^nN_i$ is generated by $e_1^{(1)}, \dots, e_{m_1}^{(1)}, \dots, e_{1}^{(n)}, \dots, e_{m_n}^{(n)}$. Hence, $\sum_{i=1}^nN_i$ is finitely generated over $A$.           **QED**

Comment: It is ok. Or simply: $\sum_{i\in I}\operatorname{span}(e^{(i)})=\operatorname{span}(\cup_{i\in I}\operatorname{span}(e^{(i)}))=\operatorname{span}(\cup_{i\in I}e^{(i)})$ (even when $I$ is infinite).

Comment: Yes, you show that the union of the generators of the separate submodules $N_i$ defines a generating set for the sum of submodules $\sum_{i=1}^nN_i$. So, you agree that since the union is finite and the generating family $(e^{(i)})$ of each submodule $N_i$ is finite per assumption, the finite sum $\sum_{i=1}^nN_i$ of finitely generated submodules $N_1, \dots, N_n$ has no choice but to be finitely generated, as well, right?

Comment: Right, i.e. if $I$ is finite and each $e^{(i)}$ is finite then $\cup_{i\in I}e^{(i)}$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!